# Solving an initial value problem with radical

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on solving the following initial value problem:

$$ \frac{dr}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{r}} $$

where r(0) = R and k is a positive constant

After separation of variables I get:

$$ \frac{dr}{\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{r}}}=dt $$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{r}}$$

$$\frac{dr}{\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{r}}} = dt $$
$$ \frac{2}{3|k|}d(r^{3/2}) = dt $$
$$r^{3/2} = \frac{3|k|}{2}t+cst $$

$$r =  (\frac{3|k|}{2}t+cst)^{2/3} $$

then you can get the cst with r(0) = R
pay attention to sign within, it must be positif

Comment: Where did the variable 's' come from?

Comment: @Bob it's a variable named cst not three variables

Answer (score 0):

The left side is $\frac 1kr^{\frac 12} dr$  Can you integrate that?

Comment: Yes, but my answer keeps on getting rejected when I solve for the initial condition.